# Why does my font face work on local host, but when transfer to server it doesn't

Tags: css, font-face

I downloaded a .ttf custom font.  It works great(only on chrome) on my local host. However, when I transfer it to another server and run site from there it doesn't.

The following is my css for the font face :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GANG BANG CRIME';
    src: url('../fonts/GANG BANG CRIME.ttf') format("truetype"), 
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body  
{

    width:              1000px;
    color:              #4149e1;
    margin:             auto;
    font-family:        Gang Bang Crime, Calibri, Helvetica/*for Mac*/, Verdana, Arial, sans-sarif;/*if can't find font, everything after first font is alternate font*/
    background-color:#1A1A1A;

}
```

Comment: Does the server send the proper MIME type when it serves the file?

Comment: @Tomalak  Im not sure.  I'm new to Web Development.  How do I check this?

Comment: Open the browser console (F12), switch to the network tab, reload your page. Look at the response headers for your font files. They come up with status 200 and a certain Content-Type value on your machine. Compare that to what you get from the server.

Comment: Gang Bang Crime, what a good name~ lots of imagination :D

Answer (score 1):

Did you upload the ttf onto the another server from local host, too?
If the another server is Unix/Linux, it'd care spaces in the file path. Escape spaces in ttf file name by back slash.

Comment: "Backslashes" is not correct. Spaces in URLs must be escaped using `%20`, but the browser usually does that on its own. `url('../fonts/GANG BANG CRIME.ttf')` would send a request for `http://foo.com/fonts/GANG%20BANG%20CRIME.ttf` to the server. A valid point however would be that Unix/Linux servers have case-sensitive file names.

Comment: This might be off topic...but may you provide situations in which I would not use a Unix/Linux server?

Comment: JeffOrris check case sensitive that @Tomalak told. In your body style, the font name is not all upper case.

Comment: @JeffOrris Yes, that is off-topic. If falls into the "smug favorite OS flame bait" category and has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: @Tomalak @wataru  Thank you both...you are officially `THE%20MAN` ;)